# Do I have to unwrap the cup again?

Tags: uv

During the tutorial, We unwrap a cup and cut off the handle and the circles. That worked fine. You take UV squares and turn the unwrap into a grid of sorts. That worked great also. Now I am supposed to go into UV Editing and change the grid on the water drops. My unwrap grid is gone. I watched the video again but do not see how Andrew Price is pulling that grid up on top of the water jpg.

Do I have to unwrap all this again? The first pic is what I get when I just go into UV Editing. The second pic is what happens when I start pushing buttons at will trying to bring back the grid.
[image: Unwrap missing]

[image: multiple unwrap]

Comment: What do you mean by *"...pushing buttons at will trying to bring back the grid."*? Did you press random keys? In the first screenshot, you are in *Object* mode (viewport on the right side) but you need to be in *Edit* mode like in screenshot 2. When you in *Edit* mode, select the whole mesh (key A). Then the UV map should appear in the UV map editor (left side).

Comment: Yes, I was clicking any button that was clickable.  I found the unwrap when in object mode, but I now have 3 of the meshes.  2 are the roundish ones, the other is the rectangle.  I saved my file prior to frustrated button clicking.  I pulled it up again and get the second pic with the unwrapped and uvsquared grid, as well as, another unwrapped cup.  During my frustration I tried to unwrap it a second time.  Can I somehow delete the second unwrap?

Answer (score 0):

**Screenshot 1** To see the UV maps do the following...

1. select the object in the outliner. You can select more than one object if you want to unwrap them on the same UV map
2. switch to *Edit Mode*
3. make sure you have selected the correct UV map
4. select the faces you want to see. Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select them all and it should reveal the whole UV map. You can unwrap the object(s) with <kbd>U</kbd>. The *Unwrap* operation requires seams (the red lines). *Smart UV Project* does not need seams.
5. in the UV editor you can see the UV islands now. If you select only a few faces in the viewport then only those are shown here. You can drag them around and they will become separated islands. This way you don't need a seam.
6. if you're looking for a specific face you can activate the *UV Sync Selection* mode. In this mode, any face you select in the UV editor will be selected in the viewport and vice versa. Tip: Use *Face Selection* mode (<kbd>3</kbd>). In this mode, vertices of connected islands are automatically selected. Turn sync off, if you want to move a UV island.

[image: screenshot 1 with remarks]

**Screenshot 2**

1. here in the section *Object Data Properties > UV Maps*, you can select the UV map that you want to edit. The camera icon specifies the map that is used for the render. In this list, you can also add more UV maps and delete unnecessary ones.

In the Image Editor on the left, you can select an image that is displayed for the UV map.

[image: screenshot 2 with remarks]

Comment: Thank you.  This makes sense and is easy to follow.  I did manage to pull up the flat grid without the second unwrap but the blue water tile is not on my screen.  I took a chance and just scaled the grid and my drops on the glass shrunk down.  I would not have even had any inclination on this without your help.